# C# Reading From NetworkStream using StreamReader

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader, streamwriter, networkstream

I'm a Java Developer Trying to build a Simple C# TCP Client. however for the life of me I can't figure out how to get this bloody thing to work. Here is my TCPClient code. BTW, I stole this directly from msdn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

```
    public static void Connect(String server, int port, String message)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a TcpClient.
            // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
            // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
            // combination.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
            //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.

            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = new Byte[256];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Here is my Java Server.

```
private ServerSocket socket;
private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
boolean listening = true;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private HMSAgentService() {

}

public HMSAgentService(int port) {
    try {
        this.socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        logger.debug("Agent Service listening on port : " + port);
        this.jaxbContext = HMSAgentUtil.getJAXBContext();
        while (listening) {
            new AgentServiceThread(socket.accept(), jaxbContext).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

It simply starts off a new thread when it receives a client connection.
Now my problem is that The program never moves past the stream.Write(). Also the server never receives the message. Only after I call Stream.close() does the server receive the message. But that essentially closes the connection and the client can't receive any more messages. Why is happening. I've tried using Sockets, StreamWriters, StreamReaders and its the same story.
At this point i'm contemplating using The Asynchronous method, but I'm trying to keep the program as simple as possible, since there is no need for it. Is there anyway of signaling the end of a Write?

Comment: Try to flush the stream: `stream.Flush();` But, iirc, a NetworkStream doesn't buffer anything, so this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the `NoDelay` property on the TcpClient.

Comment: Perhaps your server waits for more data. Are you sure `message` is correct? maybe a cr-lf at the end? If it is a webserver , you may think of use of `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` not to bother with http header manually.

Comment: okay. ive tried to send a simple text message and it works. i think the problem is the xml document. i see that the xml serializer formats the xml string with indents and new lines.  is there a way of preventing this?

Comment: I don't think its the XML formatting or indentation. Here is the sample xml string request that fails.
`message = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ClientRequest><Product>AGENT</Product><Method>GET_SYSTEM_INFO</Method><ClientId>UMOHB</ClientId><Params><Param Value=\"umohb\" Key=\"username\" /><Param Value=\"password\" Key=\"password\" /><Param Value=\"localhost\" Key=\"hostname\" /></Params></ClientRequest>";`

Comment: Is there something in my xml tags that's causing the fail? @L.B

Comment: When I paste your xml to notepad I see some garbage chars in ClientId tag

Comment: @L.B I see the whitespace character, just a copy and paste issue. no space in my string. my original message was generated by XmlSerializer
here is the code from the console.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClientRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Product>AGENT</Product>
  <Method>GET_SYSTEM_INFO</Method>
  <ClientId>UMOHB</ClientId>
  <Params>
    <Param Value="umohb" Key="username" />
    <Param Value="password" Key="password" />
    <Param Value="localhost" Key="hostname" />
  </Params>
</ClientRequest>`